# How to calculate pixel in `background-position` automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create an animated image from a static image and put it into `<div>` like Facebook sticker.

Here is the image demo:

[image]

There are 17 tuzkies. I think about `background-position` to *split* 1 tuzki in a time and use `setInterval` to display `next` tuzki, like this:

```
 <style>
.preview {
   background-image: url("http://googledrive.com/host/0B-UH4_eX_YisdlJ4cU9qZ1lwM3c/Tuzki1.png"); 
   background-size: 380px 304px; 
   height: 64px; 
   width: 64px; 
   background-position: -6px -6px;
}
</style>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

So, `background-position: -6px -6px` is the first tuzki. And my question is: How to get the second, the third... tuzki (in pixel)?

```
$('.preview').hover(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
      var pos = $('.preview').css('backgroundPosition').split(' ');
      var xPos = parseInt(pos[0].split('px')[0]); // get x position
      var yPos = parseInt(pos[1].split('px')[0]); // get y position

      //do something to get next tuzki: xPos and yPos

      $('.preview').css('background-position', xPos + 'px ' + yPos + 'px');
   }, 100);
});
```

Comment: have you tried animation steps - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought that may help: `0%` puts the image at the left/top, and `100%` puts it at the right/bottom.

With this in mind, since you have five frames, just divide by four: `0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%`

You now have perfectly positioned frames. Apply a similar principle for the vertical position (`0%, 33%, 67%, 100%` - consider adding an empty row so you can use 0-25-50-75-100 again) and you don't have to worry about pixel sizes any more.

Keep in mind that it's probably easier to save the *frame number* and modify that, then calculate xy from that.

Comment: Sound like `Get pixel from percentage`. The first Tuzki width = (image width * 0.2), height = (image height * 0.25). Is it right?

Comment: Please post a working example if you get this to work, for completeness sake.